# Is it possible to join a MySQL query to a PHP ODBC query? (Sage 50 UK)

Tags: php, mysql, odbc

Please accept my apologies if this has been covered, I have searched Stack Overflow but I am yet to find anything that matches what I want to achieve.

I am developing a CRM that connects to Sage 50 UK. Sage uses a proprietary database known as a 'flat file'. However, you can run queries against the database using ODBC.

I am looking to perform a JOIN on the 2 databases, as each database houses certain information that I need to ORDER BY. I currently have it set up to query the Sage database first, then perform a query on the MySQL database but it's not good enough.

I haven't included any code, as I don't think that'd help in any way. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot join between two databases. You'd have to query both independently and mix the result together in PHP.

Comment: That is usually true but there is software called sqljoinengine which can join multiple databases over different ODBC data sources.

Comment: There are even solutions that pretend to be one single SQL database and behind this facade work with MS Access, Excel or flat files, as well as Oracle or DB2 and do some crazy stuff. I wonder how this would ever allow transactional consistency, but apart from details, even this solution or yours can only query two databases and emulate the join. Not having these external solutions, the only thing available is to do the join operation in PHP.